# how to run mkdir command with volumes in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Please help me!!!

I can't figure out the logic of that.I have a dockerfile file as follows.

```
FROM php:fpm

RUN touch /var/www/html/foo.php
```

this is my compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
web:
container_name: phpx
build : .
ports:
- "80:80"
volumes:
  - ./code:/var/www/html
```

I never see foo.php in my directory named code. How can I see foo.php?

what is the logic of it? When I remove the 'volumes' parameter, it creates in the container, but my code directory does not see.Because it is not synchronous.

How do I write a code in the dockerfile file?

Comment: So you see the file in the container being created?

do a  `docker exec -it phpx /bin/bash`
once inside the container, check folder /var/www/html/ to see if the file is there.
try /bin/sh if the above doesn't work

Another possibility is that user running docker does not have the permission to access  /code folder of the host system.

Are you by any chance doing this on windows?

Answer (score 1):

To create a directory you can use either

```
FROM php:fpm

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/
RUN touch /var/www/html/foo.php
```

or

```
FROM php:fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
RUN touch /var/www/html/foo.php
```

Now lets build the image like

```
docker build -t phpx .
```

Now running like this

```
docker run -it phpx /bin/sh
```

Now you can find the `/var/www/html/foo.php` file the location.

If you try to mount the empty directory which is `code` in our case, it will delete everything in the `mounted` directory.

```
docker run -it -v full_host_path/code:/var/www/html phpx /bin/sh
```

The possible solution for your problem could be to put `foo.php` inside `code` and mount the `code` dir.

Comment: None of this is what I'm saying in my working directory (host) in the code directory does not show foo.php. Just a bash content called # # there with ls -la and I can see foo.php

Comment: The possible solution for your problem could be to put foo.php inside code and mount the code dir. Remove the creation of foo.php in the image/container. Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you might want to look at.
In your Dockerfile you need to provide permission for the user to access the location in the container. This was why the file was not being created.

```
FROM php:fpm  
RUN chown $user --recursive /var/www/html && touch /var/www/html/foo.php
```

I made these changes and i was able to get the file on my host.

Comment: What's the error? That works for me just fine. Also that's $user (without space)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried what you said but still can not get a result.I still can't see the foo.php file in the code folder on the host.I didn't find out where I was doing wrong.